# Duplicating CDN content under different domains

Tags: seo, cdn

I have the english version of my site under `mysamplewebsite.com`, I serve all of the image content from `cdn.mysamplewebsite.com`. I also have the localized versions of the `.com` site under top level country domains where the language is different (spanish, german, etc...). My idea is that I would create a new cdn for all of the localized sites and serve the same images (images already stored at `cdn.mysamplewebsite.com`) like this:

```
cdn.mysamplewebsite.de
cdn.mysamplewebsite.jp
cdn.mysamplewebsite.fr
...
```

So basically every domain would have it's own CDN url, but the content and the url structure would be the same:

```
cdn.mysamplewebsite.com/photos/img1.jpg // for usa
cdn.mysamplewebsite.de/photos/img1.jpg // for germany
cdn.mysamplewebsite.jp/photos/img1.jpg // for japan
cdn.mysamplewebsite.fr/photos/img1.jpg // for france
```

My question is that is it a real duplication of the images? Honestly I wouldn't like to use `.com` links on the `.jp` site for example. This is why I want to clone the same cdn under different country domains. If there is a better solution, any other suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of ordinary organics, not it won't affect you. In terms of Google image search rankings then, Google is likely to choose the first source it discovers. Google doesn't care about duplicate images, stock images for example are used by hundreds of thousands of sites, never any problem.

Unless you have a good reason to use `.com`, `.de`, `.fr`, then its pretty pointless and in fact better to use one for caching purposes should one user go from one country to the next.

You should also be aware that there is hardly any benefit from using multiple domains to serve your normal content, in fact a lot of evidence supports using /folders/ is preferred since the domain authority is shared across one domain. If you receive links on `.jp`, then don't expect any benefit from those links on the `.com`. I would only ever suggest multiple domains if its a enterprise with editors and publishers in those countries.